# git conflict rename / lots of file changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a long running feature branch, which has started with the renaming of the main folder of my web application, but has fairly contained changes otherwise.

On my master branch, I have in parallel made lots of file changes.

On merge, there are now conflicts for every changed file on master due to the rename.

What is the best strategy to resolve this?

Comment: Consider rebasing your feature branch onto the latest master tag first: ```git rebase -i master```. It might result in fewer merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I start the rebase I get the same conflicts when the rename commit is reached, which is straight at the start. I tried skipping the rename, bu then the next commit fails

Comment: I'm afraid you might need to either manually resolve the conflicts or reapply the change as a patch - my git skills are insufficient to advise any easier approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is no silver bullet for conflict of rename/lots of file changes.
You need resolve conflict according your branch difference, it seems many manually merge processing is inevitable for your case.

The most important is that you should reconsider your [workflow](https://git-scm.com/about/distributed). A long running feature branch is not recommended in git philosophy.

Comment: so is there any way to allow rename and code changes in 2 different branches at all, or do I need to serialize all code changes for a rename?